# Переход по страницам сайта без перезагрузки всей страницы с помощью Ajax

Tags: xml, jquery, ajax, javascript, php

Как сделать переход по страницам сайта без перезагрузки всей страницы?
Подскажите, как это сделать или дайте какой-нибудь пример. А еще, кто знает хороший видеокурс или книжку по нему (Ajax)?
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var getRequest = {
      send: function(url, idHtml,data) {
                             if(!url)
                                  return false; 
                             jQuery.ajax({
                             url: url,
                             data: data, //Это Массив с элементами для передачи 
                             type: "POST",
                             success: function (callback) {
                                       jQuery("#" + idHtml).html(callback);
                             },
                              error: function () {
                                       alert("Error ger response from server");
                              }

                       });
      }

}
```

Чтобы не пришлось особо ничего переделывать в текущем варианте добавляем :

```
jQuery("a").click(function(event) {
           getRequest.send(event.target.attr.href, "#MyBigAjaxElement", NULL);
           return false;
});
```

где-то в коде.

```
<a href="link.php">Идем сюда</a>
<div id="MyBigAjaxElement"></div> //Сюда попадет то, что мы получим при клике по ссылке выше.
```

P.S. Сорри, писал код практически на коленке...в пьяном состоянии в маршрутке с телефона.
Мог где-нибудь очепятаться :)

=======================Специально для Бориса.
Суть того, что ты написал мне так и не ясна :)

"а если у тебя 500 фоток и ты хочешь сделать как топикстартер. то биш пусть на странице по 20 фоток и полуится 25 страниц фоток" <--- это я понял. Хорошо, я могу кол-во фоток послать и в Json-е => знаю размерность "топикстартера". => если мне нужно подгружать по 20 фоток, то:

```
var ph_arr = [/Массив URL фотками/]; 
var htm = ""; 
for (var i = start_photo_elem; i < (start_photo_elem + 20); i++ ) { 
         if (ph_arr.length == i) break; 
         htm += <img src ='ph_arr[i] + "' />" 
} 
jQuery("#photo-div-1").append(htm);
```

Где:

- ph_arr - массив со ссылками на фото.
- start_photo_elem - элемент, с которого мне начинать отсчитывать 20 картинок.
- htm - контейнер с получившимся контентом для моего "photo-div-1"

Ну и получится то, что ты будешь подгружать картинки только тогда, когда они действительно будут нужны и при этом без перезагрузки основного контента.

Comment: ну ладно. в первом скрипте ты передаешь что-то пост запросом. а потом 
   var ph_arr 
откуда? я и написал что можно сделать RESTFul api для совего сайта. а не о том как вставить фотки и т.д. а фотки были примером.

Comment: мы не поняли друг друга) ты написал ему скрипт с POST запросом, а я описал более глобально. как то так вобщем))

Answer (score 0):

json. на сервере делайте отдачу данных в json формате(ну или в xml но это как то не камильфо) например у вас есть галерея и при запросе /gallery.json вы будете отдавать массив с названиями, описанием и путями к фотографиям с  лимитом например в 10 штук.

а на клиенте подружайте фотографии через тотже $.get(); 
создайте объект Photo с параметрами типа описания, пути и тп. заполните массив из объектов(данные из $get ) и вставляйте их в DOM.

Comment: эмм... смысл подгружать фотографии c помощью JS?
Я могу создать элемент IMG с указанием src своей фтографии :)

jQuery("#photo-div-1").append("<img src='" .link_to_img. "' />");

Собственно, увидим результат :)

Comment: эм а если у тебя 500 фоток и ты хочешь сделать как топикстартер. то биш пусть на странице по 20 фоток и полуится 25 страниц фоток, и нужно что бы переход по страницам не перезагружал "всю страницу" в браузере. то ты 500 фоток через  jQuery("#photo-div-1").append("<img src='" .link_to_img. "' />"); будешь делать?